# How to read xml compressed data written in file in hexadecimal binary format in java?

Tags: java

I have a situation in which I have XML compressed data in the hexadecimal binary format in a file and I want to decompress this data.
Here is the compressed hexadecimal 42 byte.

```
String hexadecimaldata = "2002a4050240d044100041d084250a42c0040101080201144e1102013c460804410459441024311e4310"

String hexArray[] = hexadecimaldata.split("(?<=\\G..)");
for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    arr[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hexArray[i + 2], 16);
}
byte[] output = decompressorr.decompressByteArray(arr);
```

and I am using inflator to read this compressed XML data but I am getting an error:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check

Here is the code where I am reading this XML compressed byte[] data.

```
public byte[] decompressByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
    byte[] output = null;
    try {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater(true);

        inflater.setInput(bytes);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Can you suggest me the solution for this?

Comment: Can you please share a full example and how you compressed the data?

Comment: Even I don't know I have only compressed XML data. We have to extract actual data from this compressed XML data.